# Hash-range partitioning in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

Does YugabyteDB use [hash-range partitioning](https://ben.kirw.in/2018/12/02/hash-range-partitioning/) or just plain old hash partitioning? seems like hash-range partitioning would speed up the addition and removal of nodes.

The linked post explains the advantages of hash-range partitioning over hash-modulo partitioning for repartitioning:

> With hash-modulo partitioning, repartitioning is a “global” operation:
> each output partition depends on every input partition. With
> hash-range partitioning, repartitioning is “local” and has a much
> narrow set of dependencies. This can have really meaningful
> consequences for reliability and performance. For example, suppose we
> lose a machine that holds one of our output partitions. If we’re using
> hash-modulus partitioning, we’ll have to refetch the data from all our
> input partitions; with hash-range partitioning, we’ll only have to
> contact one or two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is what YugabyteDB does. The distribution to tablet is a range of hash value (hash value from 0 to 65535).

Example:

```sql
create table demo (a int primary key) split into 3 tablets;
```

Will create 3 tablets split at [0x0000, 0x5555) , [0x5555, 0xAAAA) , [0xAAAA, 0xFFFF).
[image]